# Where should I install webkit's plugin?

Tags: html, c, linux, flash, webkit

I want to use webkitGTk to play html videos or local videos ,so it need some plugins such as libflashplayer.so .I want to know where should I install these plugins and how to found it? 
My wor environment:
ubuntu11.10;webkitGTK;GTK+3.0;

Comment: I found path /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins and it have plugins as follows:

Comment: flash-mozilla.so            libjavaplugin.so
flashplugin-alternative.so  libmozgcu.so
gecko-mediaplayer-dvx.so    libtotem-cone-plugin.so
gecko-mediaplayer-qt.so     libtotem-gmp-plugin.so
gecko-mediaplayer-rm.so     libtotem-mully-plugin.so
gecko-mediaplayer.so        libtotem-narrowspace-plugin.so
gecko-mediaplayer-wmp.so    libvlcplugin.so
libflashplayer.so

Comment: And if I want to play swf files by html page what should I install?

Comment: If you're able to figure this out, please update with answer as I know there are others waiting to here a result too :)

Answer (score 0):

How to install step by step flash player for linux.

When you trying to install the flash player for your linux operating system, you download file libflashplayer.

Step 1: Go to Adobe website and download you suitable version of flash player libflashplayer.so 32-bit/64bit . Then extract it to libflashplayer.so File.

```
[http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer10.html][1]
```

Step 2:

cd to the folder has file libflashplayer.so and install

If you are using FireFox:

```
sudo mv libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so
```

If you are using Google Chrome + Firefox

```
sudo mv libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so

sudo mkdir /opt/google/chrome/plugins

sudo cp /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so /opt/google/chrome/plugins
```

Comment: I did it as you told me and firefox and chromium-browser works now,but my webkit application still misssing plug-in

Comment: And I have set "enable-plugins" "enable-scripts"  TRUE

Comment: The .flv videos I want to display is in swf files,so should I install swf plugin? and what plugin should I install?